# WooCommerce - a hook for featured products shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following shortcode to show featured products on my custom page:

`[products limit=”6″ columns=”3″ orderby=”rand” visibility=”featured” ]`

It works correctly with WooCommerce 3.7.0. The problem I'm having is that I would like to add a quantity input field to each product, before Add to cart button. I already have a function to do this for Shop and Category pages:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'taisho_quantity_field', 9 );`

Unfortunately for featured products listed via this shortcode it has no effect. Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: I think your custom page needs to be a WC archive page - the after_shop_loop_item hook only works on those.

Comment: I Agree @jasie what you said

Comment: @jasie if you look at [woocommerce tagged questions on Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), you can read (just before the threads list): ***"OFF TOPIC. Questions *specific* for this e-commerce plugin have their own forum at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce.

"***… Most of "Woocommerce" questions there are "on-hold" or/and "closed" as off topic. So know you know :)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Damn I oversaw that. Thanks for caring to explain! (I feel like these comments got OT so I deleted mine, hope that's okay.)